# How to get rid of the use of "end" in loops(python) for only the last element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

By using `end="-"` I got this loop. I want to remove that `'-'` for the last element.

```
  m=4
  n=1
  for i in range(1,4):
      for x in range(5,n,-1):
          print(" ",end="")
      n+=2  
      for y in range(3,3-i,-1):
          print(y,end="-")
      for z in range(m,4):
          print(z,end="-")
      m-=1  
      print()
```

Output:

```
           3-
       3-2-3-
    3-2-1-2-3-
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `end`, you can actually use `sep`, which only separates **between** elements which sounds like what you want. This will even reduce your loops a bit.

You will have to change the prints to be something like: `print(*range(m, 4), sep='-')`.

The *spaces* (`' '`) loop is also not necessary and can be a single `print`, so your whole code can look like:

```py
m = 4
n = 1
for i in range(1, 4):
    print(" " * abs(5-n), end='')
    n += 2
    print(*range(3, 3-i, -1), *range(m, 4), sep='-')
    m -= 1
```

It is also possible to only use the loop variable `i` and avoid maintaining `m` and `n`. So the code can be reduced to:

```py
m = 4
for i in range(1, m):
    print(" " * abs(5-i*2+1), end='')
    print(*range(3, 3-i, -1), *range(m-i+1, m), sep='-')
```

which gives:

```
    3
  3-2-3
3-2-1-2-3
```

Finally, to make it more *reasonable* by `m` being the range being printed, and making it completely generic to allow any `m` you can do:

```py
m = 4
for i in range(1, m+1):
    print(" " * (m*2-i*2), end='')
    print(*range(m, m-i, -1), *range(m-i+2, m+1), sep='-')
```

Which will now print up-to `4`:

```
      4
    4-3-4
  4-3-2-3-4
4-3-2-1-2-3-4
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Nice work progress! Here, in my solution I am trying to is to divide the responsibilities into smaller tasks.

1. To generate the number to print
2. To print these in design format

```
m=4
n=1
max_line_length = 20

def special_print(items):
    # convert each number to string
    str_items = [str(each) for each in items]
    # prepare output string
    output_string = '-'.join(str_items)
    prefix = ' ' * (max_line_length - len(output_string))
    print(prefix + output_string)
    # try
    # print(output_string.center(max_line_length))

for i in range(1,4):
    items = []
    n+=2  
    for y in range(3,3-i,-1):
        items.append(y)
    for z in range(m,4):
        items.append(z)
    m-=1
    # print(items)
    special_print(items)
```

Output

```
                   3
               3-2-3
           3-2-1-2-3
```

**Note:**  This solution can be further simplified by Python Pros but I tried to keep simple enough for you to understand.

You can explore python string objects features like `center`, `join` and list-comprehension, len function to improve your Python skills.

Comment: I don't know why I got downvotes to my question. even it is reasonable right!!. why you people are not encouraging a beginner to ask a question? I think this is the place for only professionals. sometimes it warns me to ask a question after 3 days!! and sometimes it shows "your  question was closed". why you people do like that hah. you may be a great programmer, but we too can do sir. it will be good to ask more information about the question, if you don't understand  my question. but its not always good to close or downvote a question of a beginner. hope you understand my problem...